# Easier way to simplify?

Tags: python

Trying to write a script to simplify my cisco configs. User inputs names and passwords and the script will add them all together in a line by line document i can copy and paste from.

This is the method i've chosen (very new with python) and was wondering if there was a simpler way with functions or anything else?

```
hostname = input("Enter Hostname?" '\n')
en_secret = input("Enter Enable Password" '\n')

en_secret_script = "enable secret {}".format (en_secret)
hostname_script = "hostname {}".format(hostname)
script = '\n'.join([hostname_script, en_secret_script])


print(script)
```

Comment: Very interesting, I like what you've done!

Comment: Simpler way doing what?

Comment: the outcome of my code!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the same result with less line like this:

```
hostname = input("Enter Hostname?" '\n')
en_secret = input("Enter Enable Password" '\n')

print(f"hostname {hostname} \nenable secret {en_secret}")
```